# In Magento2 - filtering is not working when joining custom tables

Tags: magento, filtering, magento2

```
`<virtualType name="Vendor\ShippingFee\Model\ResourceModel\Area\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">shipping_fee_zone_area</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\ShippingFee\Model\ResourceModel\Area</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>`
```

shipping_fee_area_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">shipping_fee_area_listing.shipping_fee_area_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add Area</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <spinner>shipping_fee_area_listing_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>shipping_fee_area_listing.shipping_fee_area_listing_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="shipping_fee_area_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
            <storageConfig>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</param>
            </storageConfig>
        </settings>
        <aclResource>Vendor_ShippingFee::area</aclResource>
        <dataProvider class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider"
                      name="shipping_fee_area_listing_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <templates>
                    <filters>
                        <select>
                            <param name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</param>
                            <param name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</param>
                        </select>
                    </filters>
                </templates>
            </settings>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="delete">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete selected items?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Delete Area</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="shipping_fee/area/massDelete"/>
                    <type>delete</type>
                    <label translate="true">Delete</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="shipping_fee_area_listing_columns" >

        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <column name="entity_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Area ID</label>
                <sorting>desc</sorting>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>

        <column name="sub_district">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Sub District</label>
                <sorting>desc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="district">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">District</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="province">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Province</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="zipcode">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Zip Code</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="transportation_zone">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Transportation Zone</label>
            </settings>
        </column>

        <column name="zone_name">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Shipping Zone</label>
            </settings>
        </column>

        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendor\ShippingFee\Ui\Component\AreaListing\Detail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">100</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1000</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns
```

> 

Vendor\ShippingFee\Model\ResourceModel\Area\collection.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\ShippingFee\Model\ResourceModel\Area;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Vendor\ShippingFee\Model\Area;
use Vendor\ShippingFee\Model\ResourceModel\Area as ResourceArea;

/**
 * Class Collection
 * @package Vendor\ShippingFee\Model\ResourceModel\Area
 */
class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'entity_id';

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(Area::class, ResourceArea::class);
    }

    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['zone' => $this->getTable('shipping_fee_zone_master')],
            'main_table.zone_id = zone.entity_id',
            ['zone_name']
        );
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['zipcode' => $this->getTable('directory_zipcode')],
            'main_table.zipcode_id = zipcode.zipcode_id',
            ['zipcode'=>'code']
        );
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['sdz' => $this->getTable('directory_sub_district_zipcode_link')],
            'zipcode.zipcode_id = sdz.zipcode_id',
            ['sub_district_id']
        );
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['subdistrict' => $this->getTable('directory_district_sub_district')],
            'sdz.sub_district_id = subdistrict.sub_district_id',
            ['sub_district'=>'name','district_id']
        );
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['district' => $this->getTable('directory_region_district')],
            'subdistrict.district_id = district.district_id',
            ['district'=>'name','region_id']
        );
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['region' => $this->getTable('directory_country_region')],
            'district.region_id = region.region_id',
            ['province'=>'default_name','country_id']
        );
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['tz' => $this->getTable('area_transportation_zone')],
            'zipcode.code = tz.zipcode AND
            district.name = tz.district AND
            subdistrict.name = tz.sub_district AND
            region.default_name = tz.province ',
            ['transportation_zone'=>'transportation_zone']
        );
    }
}
```

after joining the tables i am not filtering is not working ,
i am getting error
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'zone_name' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `shipping_fee_zone_area` AS `main_table` WHERE  (((`zone_name` LIKE '%BKK%'))) {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'zone_name' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `shipping_fee_zone_area` AS `main_table` WHERE  (((`zone_name` LIKE '%BKK%'))) at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110, PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'zone_name' in 'where clause' at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"} []

I need working filter!!